# Is it possible to retrieve youtube's xml feed with an API key?

Tags: xml, youtube, request, youtube-api, http-get

I found out that the response from Youtube Data API is different from what I get when use the xml feed.

That is, API response is missing videos or are late at updating them! I have reported a bug on 'issuetracker'.

I can solve my problem just by fetching the publicly available xml data:
`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC8yH-uI81UUtEMDsowQyx1g`

However, I am afraid they will ban me for too many requests as I send multiple requests in an hour all day for my app.

With the API's quota, there is no problem as I would not pass the limit.

I searched but can't find anything. Something like this `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC8yH-uI81UUtEMDsowQyx1g&key=[SECRET KEY]` would be great solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there is no key you can use with the XML feed but I can assure you, you will not hit a limit. I've used the xml feed for a few years now for some projects and have run some tests and never got rate limited or banned. You can use a lot of requests on that endpoint and never get banned, but I wouldn't abuse it. You can go as low as 1 request every 30 seconds and still be fine. Depending on your usage, I would maybe stick to 1 request every 5-10 minutes.

Also, from my experience using it, I think Youtube caches the results server side, so if you keep requesting the same url, it will just send out the same page until they decide to refresh it on their end, which could be 5 minutes or 30 minutes to an hour. It always seems to change. I found that changing the url forces it to request an updated version much quicker.

So whenever you make a request, just add v={random-number-here} to the parameters, and use a random number each time.

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC8yH-uI81UUtEMDsowQyx1g&v=4296133 <-- Random number

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC8yH-uI81UUtEMDsowQyx1g&v=5342532 <-- Random number